# I have to hit enter twice to move to next cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

A few days ago, I suddenly discovered that, after editing a cell, I need to hit enter twice to move the next cell.  So basically, when I'm doing data entry, I'll type my number, hit enter twice, and then type my next number, hit enter twice, and so on.

I've tried adjusting the preference the says "After pressing RETURN, move selection [DOWN]", without effect (other than updating the direction of the 'next' cell according to whatever I had picked in the drop-down menu.

The same issue applies to using the down-arrow vs. enter.

I've seen this question asked a couple of times elsewhere on the web, but it was never answer well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Restarting Excel seemed to have solved the problem for me. Wow, I wasted way too much time on that.

Comment: "when in doubt rebout" windowsians proverb